# Django: Initialize date input dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, initialization

I'm building a simple web app where users can log new entries that have a name (`CharField`) and a date.

[image: entry input]

By default, the date is set to the current date:

```py
class EntryForm(forms.Form):
    entry_name = forms.CharField(label='New Entry', max_length=100)
    entry_date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today, widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

If users select a different date and add an entry with that date, I want the selected date to persist as new initial value when the page reloads.

I know there are a lot of related questions on setting initial values dynamically, but unfortunately, I still could achieve setting an initial value dynamically.

My view with the form looks like this:

```py
@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # get the label name and strip and convert to lower before saving it
            entry_name = form.cleaned_data['entry_name'].strip().lower()
            entry_date = form.cleaned_data['entry_date']
            entry = Entry.objects.create(name=entry_name, date=entry_date, owner=request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:index'))
    else:
        form = EntryForm()

    # other, unrelated stuff stuff ...

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

Even setting the initial value of a form field to a fixed value inside the view's `else` branch didn't work. I tried `EntryForm(initial={'entry_name': 'test'})` (also for `entry_date`) without success. Also `form.fields['entry_name'].initial = 'test'`, which didn't work either. In both cases, the from's `entry_name` remained empty when reloading the page.

What's the problem? How can I set the initial value in the form (neither for name nor for date)?
Is it somehow because the form is still unbounded?

If setting the initial value in the view worked, I think I could simply set it when the date is entered and it should stay when the page is reloaded since I pass the form (with the adjusted initial value) in the context dict when rerendering the page.

**Edit:** This is how I render my form in the template:

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ form.entry_name.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.entry_name.html_name }}" aria-label="new entry field">
    {{ form.entry_date }}

    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried this console and it works like a charm. How are you rendering your form?
`In [7]: form.as_p()
Out[7]: '<p><label for="id_entry_name">New Entry:</label> <input type="text" name="entry_name" value="testing testing one two one two" maxlength="100" required id="id_entry_name"></p>\n<p><label for="id_entry_date">Entry date:</label> <input type="date" name="entry_date" value="2020-10-21" required id="id_entry_date"></p>`

Comment: But your example does not use any initial values set by Django, right? 
I updated my question, adding the relevant part of the template

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I didn't test correctly. In fact, setting

```py
form = EntryForm(initial={'entry_date': '2020-12-12'})
```

inside my view does work fine and the date gets initialized as configured.

I guess, I just tried passing a `datetime.date` before or tested with initializing `entry_name`, but that didn't work because of how I render `entry_name` in the template.

---

To persist the previously entered date, I added an optional argument `init_date` to my `index` view, which is set according to the previously entered date:

```py
def index(request, init_date=datetime.date.today()):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            entry_name = form.cleaned_data['entry_name'].strip().lower()
            entry_date = form.cleaned_data['entry_date']
            entry = Entry.objects.create(name=entry_name, date=entry_date, owner=request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:index_with_date', args=[entry_date]))
    else:
        form = EntryForm(initial={'entry_date': init_date})
```

For that, I added another URL pattern:

```py
path('add/<entry_name>/<yyyymmdd:entry_date>/', views.add_entry, name='add_entry_with_date'),
```

With the following date converter:

```py
class DateConverter:
    regex = '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
    def to_url(self, value):
        return value

register_converter(DateConverter, 'yyyymmdd')
```